# Converting javascript functions to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript which I want to convert to jQuery...

I thought it would be easy, but it would appear I was wrong!

The code should resize a textarea depending on the amount of text entered into it.

Here's my code:

```
function haut() {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) aug();
}
function aug() {
   var h = parseInt($(this).height());
   $(this).height(h + 10);
   haut();
}
function top() {
   $(this).scrollTop(100000);
   haut();
}

$(document).ready( function() {

    $("#txt_test").keyup(function() {
        haut();
    });

    $("#txt_test").focus(function() {
        top();
    });

});
```

And here's the original code:

```
function haut(idt) {
   if (document.getElementById(idt).scrollTop > 0) aug(idt);
}
function aug(idt) {
   var h = parseInt(document.getElementById(idt).style.height);
   document.getElementById(idt).style.height = h + 10 +"px";
   haut(idt);
}
function top(idt) {
   document.getElementById(idt).scrollTop = 100000;
   haut(idt);
}

$(document).ready( function() {

    $("#txt_test").keyup(function() {
        haut(this.id);
    });

    $("#txt_test").focus(function() {
        top(this.id);
    });

});
```

Here's a jsfiddle if it helps... http://jsfiddle.net/HhRUH/

Comment: And what exactly do you have problems with?

Comment: there's really no reason to upgrade your original code to jquery. you're not doing anything with the jquery objects that cant be done with the DOM objects, all you're doing is complicating the code and losing performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please describe your problems specifically when you're asking a question.

So far I see you have the wrong code for binding handlers. It should be:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $("#txt_test").keyup(haut);

    $("#txt_test").focus(top);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can use `$(this)` in `keyup(function() { ... });` is because of how it was called by the jQuery implementation. See javascript's `.call` and `.apply` for more information about setting context (`this`) manually.

In your code, you're not using `haut.call()`, but `haut()`, which will not set the `this` context. Therefore `this` means something different in haut when it's invoked like `$('*').keyup(haut)` than when it is invoked like `$('*').keyup(function() { haut(); });`. The same goes for your calling `aug()` from `haut`.

Answer (score 0):

just send parameter to `aug`

```
function haut(idt) {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) aug(idt);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HhRUH/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're using `this` wrong. Pass the element instead:

```
function haut(element) {
   if (element.scrollTop() > 0) aug(element);
}
function aug(element) {
   var h = parseInt(element.height());
   element.height(h + 10);
   haut(element);
}
function top(element) {
   element.scrollTop(100000);
   haut(element);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txt_test").keyup(function() {
        haut($(this));
    });

    $("#txt_test").focus(function() {
        top($(this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are losing scope. You can use:

1) dmitry's answer(and I think the best one)

```
$("#txt_test").keyup(haut);
$("#txt_test").focus(top);
```

2) or if you want to do some more things in the callback, you can do it
with using call():

```
$("#txt_test").keyup(function()
{
    haut.call(this);
    alert('...');
});
$("#txt_test").focus(function()
{
    top.call(this);
});
```